# Unit Of Work and Repository pattern done wrong?

Tags: repository-pattern, unit-of-work, cqrs

I've seen a lot of examples of Repository pattern on the Internet with the following or similar signature:

```
public void IRepository<T>
{
    void Insert(T object);
    void Update(T object);
    void Delete(T object);
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

What puzzles me is why are CUD elements part of the Repository pattern?
According to [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), CUD operations should be part of Unit of Work pattern.

I have been using Fowler's method with EF for years and it works quite well. I assume that it would work just fine with any other ORM.

I am interested if somebody can explain, from architectural and logical point of view, why should we put CUD operations in Repository pattern? It is obvious that both methods work, but why should we do one over the other? Isn't Fowler's style more in CQRS spirit?

Answer (score 1):

The Unit of Work, as described in the link you provide, keeps track of what has do be changed in the database. It keeps track, doesn't update. At the end *it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work* (quote from your link). Committing the unit of work boils down to calling (usually several) Repositories to do the actual CUD operations **in one go**

Comment: That still doesn't explain why do repository patterns have CUD operations. What's their purpose? As you said, UoW keeps track of changes to the database and commits them in a single transaction (one more feature of UoW). So, why do I need them in a Repository pattern? What's their purpose there?

Comment: If you didn't have Repository, how would you commit your changes to the actual database? Would your UoW know JDBC or JPA or change when underlying persistence changes? This is a totally different concern than UoW and is handled by Repository.  UoW doesn't talk JDBC, it leaves that to Repository.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JDBC. I'm a Microsoft dude :). I presume they're means to connect to the DB and read and write from them. Now, if UoW tracks changes to the DB, why shouldn't it know about the DB? Otherwise, how would it track the changes and commit them to the DB?

Comment: Well, that is the whole point.  UoW knows what but not how. Repository knows how. Of course, you are free to let UoW know how to connect to the database and also do user input validation, and maybe some business logic, why shouldn't it?